# Autodesk Forge Visual Clusters Extension

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to use the Visual Clusters forge extension but I can not find any documentation on it. I am able to load and activate it by writing:

```
 const clusterExt: any = await viewer?.loadExtension(
      'Autodesk.VisualClusters',
    )
    clusterExt.setLayoutActive(!clusterExt.layoutActive)
```

but I would like to get some data back from it and monitor when certain clusters are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with my research, there is no built-in API in the extension for this, but we can do some hacking by using [Javascript HTML DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) to add a click callback on cluster labels.

```js
const clusterExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.VisualClusters');
const { gizmoController } = clusterExt;

gizmoController.labels.forEach(label => {
    label.container.addEventListener('click', event => {
        let idx = gizmoController.labels.findIndex(label => label.container == event.target);

        if( idx <= -1 ) return;

        let label = gizmoController.labels[idx];
        let gizmo = gizmoController.gizmos[idx];
        let clusterLayout = clusterExt.sceneLayout.clusterLayouts[idx];

        console.log(label, gizmo, clusterLayout);
    });
});
```